# Вызывается постоянно 301 ошибка

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

Произошло это когда я решил попробовать изменить статус в мидлвере c 401 на 301. Теперь когда вернул обратно статус и текст который возвращается не меняется. Открыл другой проект, теперь и там это фигня

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = function (req, res, next){
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        next()
    }
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1] // Beerer
        if (!token){
            res.status(401).json({message: "Не авторифывфывфывзован"})
        }
        const decoded  = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY)
        req.user = decoded
        next()
    } catch (e){
        res.status(401).json({message: "Не sdasd"})
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094920/4496422